# Tap on iPhone from Mac

Tags: ios, click

I have an iPhone 7 and I have a Google Cardboard that doesn't have a magnetic clicker. I would like to use an app, but it requires me to either tap the screen or use the VR clicker to click. Can I setup some sort of "tapper" on Mac so when I click a key on my Mac it taps the screen of my iPhone? (Software Program)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible for an application to control an iPhone in this way without jailbreaking due to iOS restrictions.

If the device is jailbroken, you may be able to install a VNC server on the iOS device like [Veency](https://cydia.saurik.com/info/veency/) and use Screen Sharing on the Mac such that you can click on the Mac and the click will emulate a tap on the iOS device.