# iOS Bluetooth "mouse" for navigation and Virtual Reality Apps

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth, mouse, third-party

I bought a set of BlitzWolf VR Goggles to use with iPhone X, and the headset came bundled with a Bluetooth VR hand controller/mouse.  In order to test this setup I downloaded a VR Roller Coaster app.  And this is where my issues began, as in order to actually enter the VR environment I had to:

1. Clip my phone into the VR Goggles faceplate, but not close it up
2. Use my fingers on the phone to select the VR Roller Coaster App and start it executing.
3. Close up the goggles.
4. Put the headset on my head.
5. Enjoy missing out the first few moments of the game.

This is not the VR experience I was sold on.  I had imagined that:

1. I would pop the phone in the goggles
2. Place the goggles on my head
3. Use the VR controller to navigate my phone and to initiate the VR app
4. etc. etc.

The bundled VR controller did not perform the functionality I desired (and its instructions imply that it cannot/does not do what I want, however it may do so under Android).

Does iOS support any bluetooth controller that will give me the VR experience that I want? EG an onscreen mouse cursor of some sorts.

Comment: I don't think any iPhone is compatible with any BT mouse.  Have you asked the BlitzWolf, or their support forums, how this can be done?

Comment: @fsb I think the supplied controller is a bust. It is 3rd party and not BlitzWolf controller (and BlitzWolf doesn't offer such controllers on their site).  The instructions that came with it suggest that under iOS it can only used to perform "Pause, play, and volume +/- etc" functionality.  It only mentions mouse mode for Android. So I think this is an iOS rather than controller issue.  That's why my question is focussed on VR experience rather than the particular hardware that I currently have. In hindsight I shouldn't have gotten this controller.

Comment: I'm not aware of any VR device that will give you the experience you mentioned.  Did you search for VR and iOS related questions?  Maybe someone posted an answer that can help you.

Comment: @fsb There are very few questions in here about VR.  I did search before I posted, and just took a closer look.  The closest match is https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/272324/4376

Comment: @fsb I may have to wait until the official Apple VR goggles are available (see https://www.macrumors.com/roundup/apple-vr-project/)